# Android Room - auto increment @database version number?

Tags: android, android-room

During development my Room db schema is very volatile. Every time I do any change to the schema I need to update my version number, like this;

```
@Database(version = 27,
    entities = {MyClass.class})

public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase
```

I am using fallbackToDestructiveMigration too;

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, SystemStrings.ROOM_DATABASE_NAME)
                // allow queries on the main thread.
                // Don't do this on a real app! 
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
```

Is there any way to avoid updating the version number for each "little" change? As I said, things are quite volatile right now.

Comment: you can uninstall the App or clear the App's data.

Comment: Can I do that programmatically? Doing either of those things is more work than simply updating the version number between builds. BTW, I'm debugging using a Virtual Device (AVD).

Comment: yes you can delete the database programatically using `context.deleteDatabase(database_name)` (where context and database_name are replaced respectiviely)

Comment: Why are you incrementing the version number? Leave it the same and every  time you will have a new empty database

Comment: Because if the schema changes and you don't change the version number you get this exception "Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number"

Comment: @ausgeorge got any solutuon yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleteing the database would result in it being initialised/built each time the App is run.

You could do this using :-

```
context.getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(SystemStrings.ROOM_DATABASE_NAME); //<<<< ADDED before building Database.
//Your existing code follows 
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, SystemStrings.ROOM_DATABASE_NAME)
                // allow queries on the main thread.
                // Don't do this on a real app! 
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
```

**Of course you would not have this in the real app**