# Android Room Migration Strategy

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

Is there any way to instruct Room to simply delete the database and recreate it if the schema has changed? Similar to the migration strategy seen in Entity framework commonly used in the early development of a app.

As I'm in the early stages of development of the app and schema changes will be frequent meaning writing migrations and changing version numbers would be a waste of my time.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. This is answered in the documentation of Room. Check here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions at "Gracefully handle missing migration paths"

Comment: Yes I did see and had tried it out. It still forced me to update the database version number upon schema change.

Comment: Yes and what's wrong with that? (spoiler: there's nothing wrong with that)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`. Usage pattern:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(...)
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build();
```

Comment: I had tried this but it will forces me to up the version number of the database. So by the end of the development my version number will very high? Unless i'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: Are you sure? @BenDonnelly using the above (in my sample) is NOT forcing developer to increment version number. Neither when some entity details are changed, nor when entities are added for example.

Comment: @ror I have tested this on production, even if we use fallbackToDestructiveMigration() but if we forget to update the VERSION number on every schema change, app will still crash

Answer (score 0):

Add a Debug flag and delete the database before creating it. Something like [Android Room - auto increment @database version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799779/android-room-auto-increment-database-version-number)

If you do not want it on every run then catch the Exception and then delete and create.

This should not be done on release builds though.